# Significance of login() call in both route.get() and route.post()

Tags: php, security, authentication, routes, httprequest

I'm trying to understand the source code of a given web application during the white box testing phase for a school project in software security 101. By other terms, we are trying to find security holes in the source code. When I study the index.php-file, I see that login() is called both after the get-request and the post-request:

```
$router->get('/signin/', function() {
    $controller = new \App\Controllers\SessionsController();
    $controller->login();
});

$router->post('/signin/', function() {
    $controller = new \App\Controllers\SessionsController();
    $controller->login();
});
```

The login-function in question is just a basic one, which checks if the given username and the password hash match any entry in the DB. If they do, `login()` starts a new session with the provided info.

From what I see, there is no reason to call `login()` after /signin has been rendered, only after the HTML-form in /signin has been submitted (which is done by pressing a button). Is there any logic I am missing here, or could this mean that a simple URL-injection could be possible somewhere?

Comment: I think you might need to go back a step and read up what the router is actually doing, not just assuming. From a security point of view, the problem is that there shouldn't be an option to send credentials in GET at all.

Comment: @JonStirling Ok, that's kind of what I hoped. Thanks!